# Make content before sit on top of an element (like a tab)

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to make CSS `content` before site on top of the element like a tab?

Like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
div {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0074D9;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Courer New", monospace;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: "Label";
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0074D9;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aEdTz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the left and top properties to position the element

```
div:before {
    content: "Label";
    top: -15px;  /* -height */
    left:-1px;   /* for 1px border on div */
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0074D9;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aEdTz/2/